# How to log test pass/fail results of JUnit4 to a file?

Tags: java, junit, junit4

When a given JUnit4 test runs, I want it to generate a logfile of all of its TestResults. I do not want to invoke this via CI/ant/maven. **I want this to run anytime the JUnit test is called  from anywhere.** If that is not possible, then I would like to write my own runner which problematically invokes my AllTestSuites class and logs all the results itself.

Here would be one of my test classes:

```
public class SimpleTestSuite extends TestCase{

    @Test
    public void simpleTestPass() {
        assertTrue(true);
    }

    @Test
    public void simpleTestFail() {
        assertTrue(false);
    }

    @Test
    public void simpleTestException() {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }

}
```

I included it in a TestSuite, which contains all of my test Suites to run:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({SimpleTestSuite.class, ExampleSuite.class,})
public final class AllTestSuites {}
```

I want to invoke AllTestSuites and have it generate a log file such as below. Remember, I prefer to capture what is on the JUnit4 framework's result bus, and not to reinvent/create a new test runner.

```
simpleTestPass - pass - 1/1 assertions passed
simpleTestFail - fail - 0/1 assertions passed
simpleTestException - exception - stacktrace as follows...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add logger in you Test Class and Base Test Class and define as `TestWatchMan` as below:

```
Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestCase.class);
@Rule public MethodRule watchman = new TestWatchman() {
   public void starting(FrameworkMethod method) {
      logger.info("Test {} is running.", method.getName());
   }
   public void succeeded(FrameworkMethod method) {
   logger.info("Test {} succesfully run.", method.getName());
   }
   public void failed(Throwable e, FrameworkMethod method) {
        logger.error("Test {} failed with {} reason.", 
                                                method.getName(), e.getMessage());
   }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a JUnit [TestWatcher](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/org/junit/rules/TestWatcher.html).

A TestWatcher defines following methods:

- succeeded()
- failed()
- starting()
- finished()

which you can implement to get notified of events and write them to a File.

Answer (score 0):

JUnit will output those results to the standard System.out. Perhaps you could redirect that output to a file.

```
@BeforeClass 
void redirectOut(){
    System.setOut(new PrintStream(new OutputStream() {
        @Override
        public void write(int arg0) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }));
}
```